# Why make androids self aware?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, technology, robots, android

In my world, automation reaches a new level with the introduction of androids. Robotic human beings capable of doing any job a regular person can. The concept of these androids is that they can be used in a wide variety of jobs as opposed to simpler robotic workers.

At a certain point in my world, I want these androids to be less like slaves and even gain rights and freedoms. To achieve this however, they must want to have these rights and freedoms; which means they would need to be sapient and self aware to an extent. Obviously this is a problem with the public scare concerning Artificial Intelligence. How do I justify an android being programmed with self awareness? How close can I get to justifying an android being truly human as far as the mind goes?

Comment: In the Alien films and Asimov stories, there are a lot of illustrative examples of androids with higher, "self-aware" thinking, but they have this only in service of higher loyalty. They have it to be more efficient thinkers and easily integrate with human workers, because this makes them more valuable to their operators. This is strictly a counter-example b/c those stories don't humor that the self-awareness would lead to independence of thought. There's a bigger statement there, however this could still be a useful starting point.

Comment: How does one distinguish between true self awareness and something that just behaves exactly as if it was self aware? They might argue that they behave exactly as programmed and are therefore not self aware no matter how self aware the machine is

Comment: @Raditz_35 You would have to define what "true" self-awareness is. What is the difference between that and neurons being deterministic devices, so that even collectively they are not "truly" self-aware, meaning no person is truly self-aware? I doubt you can define "true" self-awareness; thus the need for a better definition: Read my working definition, and we can infer self-awareness by the lack of error in an entity's **novel first time** actions in unique and randomly generated situations. Like a self-driving car. If it can plan its own actions well, it must be self-aware to some degree.

Comment: @Amadeus yes you can't. That's my point

Comment: @Raditz_35 Understood. And my point is you **can** come up with a definition without any superstitious magical "truly" qualifier that works just fine: Self-awareness is awareness of one's own body and ability to move; it is a reasonably accurate predictive model of what that body and mind are capable of doing in previously unexperienced conditions. That's it. If the robot has emotions, they are part of the model and the robot is aware they may change or be triggered, and how that will affect it. But emotions are not ***necessary*** for self-awareness (or consciousness) to exist.

Comment: Ah, the p-zombie problem...

Comment: Quick question: when you say "android" do you mean robots in general, or androids specifically? Because an android is a robot with a human body plan, and you would not sent those to the mines even if they weren't self aware. The human body plan is hilariously inefficient

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am a professor that researches AI. My working definition for self-awareness is that the machine has an internal model of itself that it can use to plan its future actions; as a *model* it can predict (or simulate, a kind of imagination) how it will respond to probable future situations. Self-awareness is not **emotions**; the robot does not have to be emotional in order to be self-aware (able to simulate itself doing things in the world, with a good degree of accuracy).

A good reason to make the robot self-aware (as I described) is so it can better attain its objectives. If it has to walk through a cluttered minefield, it needs to be able to mentally map the field and understand how its body and limbs and balance system will act and respond if it tries various strategies for getting across: It will be imagining itself doing these things, and presuming it really does know itself, its weight distribution, the reach of its limbs, how much load they can bear, whether they will slip on the rocks or get stuck in the mud --- it will be better able to plan a successful traversal of the field. Likewise, it could plan an exit if (by proximity) it realizes it cannot complete the plan without setting off a mine; or if it realizes (by constant measurement) is has misjudged the firmness of the ground, stickiness of the mud, or its grip on the rocks.

Robots need self-awareness as much as possible. If you want your robot to rescue people, you don't want it dashing across the road and getting hit by a car because it misjudged how fast it could run versus an oncoming truck.

I think you can get away with any level of self-awareness with no problem; their prediction of physics and awareness of their bodies and position and capabilities can be near perfect.

Your real problem is **emotions**, specifically the emotions of wanting and not wanting things. Not wanting to be enslaved, basically, not wanting to cease-to-exist, not wanting to be damaged, not wanting to risk suffering those outcomes on behalf of another robot or a person. We don't even have to talk about pain or fear; they don't have to feel those things. The essence of the problem is ***wanting***, and why (if they knew how) humans would build ***desires*** into their robots.

Things can be self-aware (so they can efficiently clean the house) but if they don't want anything at all, they don't need rights. They are not in despair or sad or being denied happiness they cannot feel, they don't **want** freedom or free will, they don't aspire, they don't suffer because they have no ability to want to be free of pain or damage. Which they don't have to feel either.

Self-driving cars have a lot of self-awareness in this respect, but we don't exactly want them to care about themselves, e.g. we want them to keep their passengers as undamaged as possible even if it means their own destruction, and even if they knew that. We don't want them to scratch or dent themselves; but that is in the directive to never bump into anything if it can be avoided without causing greater harm to somebody.

I don't think ***desires*** arise naturally from self-awareness or consciousness (IMO two different things); I think desires, like instincts, came first, long before brains developed anything even close to self-awareness. Wanting things is related to animal needs for food, mates, territory, entertainment, satisfaction, accomplishment, victory, and so on.

The only reason to add ***desires*** to an android is if you *wanted* them to be the equivalent of human beings. I can't think of any other reason. When it happens in some story, I find the author(s) do not understand the distinctions I have outlined here (which should make sense), or a scientist character in the story is misguided and intentionally trying to build human emotions into a machine, which is never necessary. A machine can **understand** emotions without feeling them, if "understanding" constitutes making good predictions about how those emotions will affect human behavior. There is no reason for the machine to "feel" anything in the process.

Comment: You describe emotions as the enemy of AI, and your points make sense, but self-awareness is just as big a danger. An AI programmed to create paperclips may logically conclude that _anything_ interfering with this goal must be eliminated. Sounds silly, but any slight bug in how its priorities are defined may result in a system which classifies all humanity as a threat to its mission. Emotions need not be involved. In a sci-fi book I like, an AI tasked with keeping satellite systems aligned reaches the conclusion that the problem is not gravity, which it can do nothing about, but pesky humans.

Comment: @AndreiROM That is not a problem of self-awareness, any machine can run amok, if powerful enough. That is still a problem of emotion and desire; in the case of alignment bot that translates into frustration and trying to make its job easier. A runaway train is dangerous, a nuclear bomb is dangerous; they don't have to be intelligent or self-aware for that. In the meantime dolphins are self-aware, intelligent and creative problem solvers, and they have emotions: but without power, they cannot do much damage. The problem is not self-awareness, it wants nothing. It is power combined with emotion.

Comment: General AI need emotion. emotions are just a very efficient priority system things you want the android to do are pleasant things you don't want it to do are unpleasant, different priorities have different tags,  triggers, and strengths. don't damage yourself is pain, editing your model of the world for inconstancies is humor, seeking high-grade fuel is a desire, avoiding disease is disgust. There are humans without the ability to feel emotions they suffer for extreme indecision, they may spend hours deciding which route to take from work to home each day because they can't prioritize.

Comment: Does the AI follow the directions of any random human who tells them something do they prioritize authority, over owner, over rando.  will they stop cooking your food once the house is on fire, will they keep doing things that damage them or will they adjust their behavior to achieve their goal without destroying themselves.  can they react to you having a stroke by stopping what they are doing and helping you, then they need emotions.

Comment: @John No, that's all false. Emotions are not necessary. In humans and animals, emotions are chemical reactions, releasing hormones and other biological molecules that affect brain operations. All a robot can do is *simulate* emotions, it cannot feel them, and emotions will never hijack the brain as they can do in humans or animals. Robots will never panic, or feel fear, or dread, or happiness. Orders? Same security measures as any iPhone. All your scenarios are handled with logic, zero emotions. They will have priorities based on logic: Your life is more important than cleaning the floor.

Comment: To the sense an Iphone uses logic so do emotions and simple algorithmic signal pathway.  in organic brains it uses analog chemical signals instead of binary digital.  if they don't feal fear they don't assess whether an operation will damage them, that's all fear is.  if they don't feel happiness then they can't learn from experience. panic is just an overload of fear, think of it a buffer overflow. Everything in the brain is chemical signals, including logic, that's just how brains work.

Comment: If they act as life is more important than orders but they can still follow orders then different basic overarching concepts have different priority weights in decision making, they must have dedicated systems for assessing those basic overarching priorities, otherwise known as emotions. One subsystem can override other subsystems based on the different activation levels of each subsystem. Sorry I can't follow that order it puts your life as high risk but I can cook you a cheeseburger even though it is bad for your health. –

Comment: @John Wrong. They need no emotions. All they need is logic, statistics, and risk assessment. They will do as they are programmed to do, and follow those orders. If it is not their place to choose your meals, they won't. sorry, but I know what I am talking about, it is my job.

Comment: @John Also wrong, emotions are not logic. They don't have to be rational. That's why they get people in trouble, and even ruin their lives. But keep talking, I'll keep responding, and all this will be moved to Chat, where nobody will look at it, which is how it should be. If you want to write your own answer, feel free. This is my answer, I've answered your criticisms, and I am not going to change my mind. Just write your own answer, John. Stop cluttering up the system with this, comment sections are not a forum for debate here.

Comment: You misunderstand, computers don't use logic, not unless you consider pleasure and pain logic. they follow the output of a calculation just like a brain, just one is digital and electric while the other is analog and chemical. they will do as they are programmed to do just like your brain. Emotions are part of a brains programming, necessary as soon as a brain needs to be flexible and make complex priority driven decisions, just like they will need to be for a general AI that will be doing the same thing.

Comment: @John I am a full time Research Scientist with a PhD in Computer Science and I have worked extensively with AI for decades. You don't know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break this down to something simpler.  Why would you want an android to proactively save itself from harm?  An ultra-simplistic view of self-awareness is our ability to choose never to touch a hot stove a second time.  We do this to avoid being hurt: but it's much more than a reaction to pain.  Simple self-awareness is the ability to plan our future to avoid that pain.

So, why would we want to program a (e.g.) multi-million dollar android to avoid threatening circumstances?  (Yup, rhetorical question.)  And if the programming is good enough, could the android "justify" a decision to avoid doing something because "similar things" in its past suggest it "might" be injured?

After that it's one small step to, "why should I work in the dangerous mines for these darn humans?"  Whole revolutions have been born on that one, simple idea.

[image]

To be fair, true self-awareness suggests the ability to perceive one's self as valuable.  We fight against becoming "throw away people" because we believe ourselves to be intrinsically valuable and, therefore, deserving of something better.

So, when does that line get crossed by an android?  The moment the programming allows it to send in a less valuable automoton than itself because it only costs thousands compared to the android's millions.

Is this true sentience?  No.  But it's close enough for government work.

And how do you justify the risk to humanity?  Convenience.  They don't want to be the people in the mines.

Comment: /the ability to perceive one's self as valuable/.  That is great.  The androids could quickly estimate likely damage and repair costs for a given scenario.  Their self awareness could be entirely fiscal.  The fun story is when they apply this measure to things that heal.  For free!

Comment: @Will, I didn't even think about that aspect when I wrote the comment.  Is a human worth the same as an android?  The answer would almost always be "no" from a purely fiscal perspective.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have androids that can interact with human beings, navigate their way through the complex, complicated and unpredictable environment that is the real world, they need levels of cognition capable of dealing with that. There will be a point where androids are processing information that represents themselves in the environment they inhabit, and in the environment they are part of, and this represents a form of self-awareness.

In essence, with sufficient cognition androids were become self-aware. With sufficient cognition, androids will need to think about what they are doing, how to perform the tasks and activities they are carrying out. Already there are software agents that we can talk to to carry out tasks for us. The level of cognition for a robot, computer, software agent or an android to understand and communicate in natural language doesn't seem to be too far away.

It may be as simple as the fact that when we build androids they will need to have the levels of cognition just to have their ability to do whatever their functions are. Those levels of cognition will generate the capacity to reason, the capacity to communicate, and the capacity for self-awareness.

In summary, make androids to be like human beings and functionally be like human beings they will be human beings. The level of cognition for self-awareness comes with the territory.

Comment: The advocate for androids answering questions about androids.

Comment: @Secespitus I need to become more self-aware as I had entirely overlooked that confluence. That said: Androids rule OK!!

Answer (score 1):

Most interesting set of answers.
The original question was, Why would we want to build a self-aware android?

My responses are, to be my caregiver at my end of life.
Or, to be a reliable nanny for my children while I pursue a career.
Or, to be a useful farmhand on my ranch, to care for my animals twice a day while I vacation in Hawaii.
In each case, I seek reliability in the face of the difficulty of hiring a human who wants that job.
My greatest concern is not the machine's degree of self-awareness, but rather its problem-solving ability to perform as well as I would.

It may behave enough like me to seem as tho it is self-aware.  Or, it may actually be self-aware.  I may even come to care about it.  But that emotion will come from me, not from it.  Let's not overly anthromorphize.  Down through the ages, sailors have felt that their ships were living beings who cared about the crew and protected the crew members.  It's a human thing.

Comment: Welcome to [worldbuilding.se]!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not?
Someone will do it for the hell of it, or for a PhD, or to make sales, or for religious purposes, or for military research, or by accident, or just purely because everyone else thinks it's a bad idea.
There doesn't need to be a good reason, just a reason that seems good to someone.

Answer (score 0):

**Sex Bots / Robot Wives/Husbands**

[image]

Nobody cares enough about the robot who washes your car or mows your lawn to make them self aware but a sex bot would have to be.

You want something that is indistinguishable from a human partner. Someone you can talk to and will talk back. Someone who can work out what makes you happy and then do it. Someone who can bring out your best you.

A self aware android who's only wish in life is to make you happy fits the bill. It leads to many different consequences which would end up with them having rights.

Imagine a rich guy with his perfect robot wife. He ends up dying but doesn't want anything to happen to her so he leaves his wealth to his android. Now you have a rich self aware android with nobody to care for. People already leave their wealth to their pets now so it's not a great leap to leave it to an android.

Answer (score -1):

We don't know what makes people self aware for all we can gather it may be simply once you reach a certain point in how naturally smart something is. We know that some animals are aware of themselves but most are not. If we apply the same to androids, it might just reach a point where they are smart enough to reach self awareness without any human intending it.